# Assistance finding the floor and ceiling of a vector

Tags: r, vector, floor, ceil

I have created vectors for months and month numbers, then for months 6-9, and from there, the mean...

```
mean(Summer)
Months[mean(Summmer)]
```

July

Now I have to use floor and ceiling functions to return upper and lower limits of months for average summer month.
I thought I was on the right track, but I'm getting errors! Thoughts?

```
months[x]
months[floor(x)] # July
months[ceiling(x)] # August
```

Comment: Example values of `months` and `x`, along with the expected result would help us provide  better feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you are doing, but here's my best effort to produce a working example in response:

```
# This is built into R and it gives month names
month.name

# Let's make seasons:
Spring = 3:5
Summer = 6:8
Autumn = 9:11
Winter = c(12,1,2)

# If each season has 3 months, then we can get out a particular monh like so:
month.name[Summer[1]]
month.name[Summer[2]]
month.name[Summer[3]]

# We can also use the min, mean, and max technique for summer:
month.name[min(Summer)]
month.name[mean(Summer)]
month.name[max(Summer)]

# But it doesn't really work for Winter:
month.name[min(Winter)]
month.name[mean(Winter)]
month.name[max(Winter)]
```

My guess is that the main confusion here is around the functionality of `floor`. Floor takes as input a vector and outputs a vector that applies the floor function (round down to nearest integer) to each element of the vector, so `floor(c(1,2,3))` will return `c(1,2,3)` and `floor(1.3)` will return `1`. Ceiling works similarly.

Hopefully this helps with whatever you are trying to do. In general, it's helpful to provide a reproducible example so that others can run the exact same code you are running and help debug your problem.